# jquery dynamic popup window

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, t-sql

what I want to do is when I click the image button, a popup window has to come up in the center of the page.below code mask it but doesn't create a popup window.one more question I want to put dynamic textbox and check box according to a store procedure from sql.shall I write the table records in a hiddenfield and how can I transfer it to the popup window?? thanks

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.btncig').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('href');
            var maskHeight = $(document).height();
            var maskWidth = $(window).width();
            $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });
            $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
            $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
            var winH = $(window).height();
            var winW = $(window).width();
            $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
            $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);
            $(id).fadeIn(2000);

        });
        $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#mask, .window').hide();
        });
        $('#mask').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $('.window').hide();
        });
    });

</script>
```

---

```
    <td>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="Imagecig" class="btncig" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/selection.png" style="margin-left:13px" OnclientClick=""/>
```

css

```
    #mask 
    {
          position:absolute;
          z-index:9000;
          background-color:#000;
          display:none;
    }


    #boxes .window
       {
         position:fixed;
         width:440px;
         height:200px;
         display:none;
          z-index:9999;
         padding:20px;
        }


    #boxes #dialog 
    {
      width:375px; 
      height:203px;
    }
```

Comment: u may need to add attribute clinetidmode='static' in asp image tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say which library you are using for your popup. If you are using jQuery UI, then your code should look like this:

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#dialog").dialog({  // <-- Initialize your dialog/popup
             autoOpen: false,
             modal: true});

       $('.btncig').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog").dialog("open"); // <-- show your dialog/popup
       });
    });
  </script>
```

You also need some html to put your fields, again you can use a number of methods to create the content dynamically, ie ajax calls etc so your html should look something like this

```
 <div id="#dialog">
     <!-- Your dynamic content goes here -->
 </div>
```

**You need to ensure that in your page you reference both the jQuery and the jQuery libraries either through CDN or locally.**

I hope this helps